# Doctrine query builder - nested queries, AS keyword, select functions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

```
SELECT t1.field1 AS foo, (SELECT ABS(SUM(amount)) FROM table2 t2) FROM table1;
```

How can I convert this query into symfony 2 doctrine query builder?

```
$results = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select(...)
           //...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$results = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('t1.field1')
  ->addSelect('abs(sum(amount)) t2')
  ->from('BundleName:Entity', 't1)
  ->leftJoin('t1.field', 'another')
  ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Maybe this works, I found a similar problem and a solution here:
[Select Subquery with COUNT() in Doctrine DQL](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/select-subquery-with-count-in-doctrine-dql/)

Or if it not works, you can create two queries for the problem, and you use the first query's result in the second query.